# What is wrong with this javascript and php code

Tags: php, javascript

I've been trying to debug this for an hour:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function initialize() {     
    alert('test');
    var latlngarr = new Array();
    var titlearr = new Array();
    <?php
        echo "latlngarr.length=".$response->total.";";
        echo "titlearr.length=".$response->total.";";
        for ($i=0;$i<$response->total;$i++){
            echo "latlngarr[".$i."] = new google.maps.LatLng(".$response->businesses[$i]->location->coordinate->latitude.",".$response->businesses[$i]->location->coordinate->longitude.");";
            echo "titlearr[".$i."] = \"".$response->businesses[$i]->name."\";";
        }
    ?>

    var myOptions = {       
        zoom: 10,       
        center: latlngarr[0],       
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
    };     
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);   
    var markerarr = new Array(titlearr.length);
    for(var i=0;i<markerarr.length;i++)
        markerarr[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlngarr[i], map: map, title:titlearr[i]});

}  
</script> 

<body onload="initialize()">
```

The error that I got is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined

When I remove that block of `PHP` code, it doesn't give me that error. Why?

**UPDATE:**

Here's where the error is:

```
$(".saved").live('click', function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $.post("update.php", {uid: my_uid, save: "no", mid: "<?php echo $mid; ?>"}, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $btn.replaceWith('<a class="save action_btn" onclick="return false;">Save</a>');   
        }, 100); //this is line 76
    });
});
```

Here's the generated JS from that initialize function:

```
function initialize() {     
    alert('test');
    var latlngarr = new Array();
    var titlearr = new Array();

    <br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total in C:\wamp\www\movie.php on line <i>89</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>711160</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\movie.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\movie.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    </table></font>
    latlngarr.length=;<br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total in C:\wamp\www\movie.php on line <i>90</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>711160</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\movie.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\movie.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    </table></font>
    titlearr.length=;<br />
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$total in C:\wamp\www\movie.php on line <i>91</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>711160</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\movie.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\movie.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    </table></font>

    var myOptions = {       
        zoom: 10,       
        center: latlngarr[0],       
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
    };     
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);   
    var markerarr = new Array(titlearr.length);
    for(var i=0;i<markerarr.length;i++)
        markerarr[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlngarr[i], map: map, title:titlearr[i]});
}
```

Comment: Show the generated, final JavaScript as it shows in the browser. And show the line that throws the error

Comment: But if he does that then he'll see what the problem is and won't need to ask the question!  That's no fun!

Comment: Easy to debug, just look at the generated javascript

Comment: Comment post-update: Your code is trying to tell you that your PHP is wrong in the movie.php. ;)

Comment: Resolve your PHP errors and then the community can look at your javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `<br />` is no javascript so that would cause an error.

As would the rest of the html echoed inside the javascript block...

As you can see it´s basically one big error message, coming from php.

Answer (score 1):

Its because its showing the data as **text** in place of **html**

Its basically a php errors thrown out by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're generating HTML into JavaScript. Doing this causes a syntax error at the first `<` as indicated by the error message. It looks like your PHP is ONLY generating HTML. If you're trying to do this, put it outside your `<script>` tags. If you're not, you're going to need to wrap the HTML in quotations (or something) so that it doesn't cause a parse error.

Also, your `$response` object doesn't have a property called `$total`, as the error message says. Be sure that you're accessing the right properties to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because there are variables that are not being used within the code, that is, variables that have not been assigned any value.
Please check the variable laws that are used one by one and delete those that are not being used